# Android activity static variables across different applications

Tags: android

I'm creating a library project that implements my subclass of Activity, then reusing it in different applications. When I set static variables for the activity in one application, does this have effect in other apps using the same class?

Comment: I'd feel better if people read basic documentation _first_ before implementing a _library_. Anyway, read about Android processes and class loader. And btw, what do you want to have static variables in an Activity class for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*When I set static variables for the activity in one application, does this have effect in other apps using the same class?*

No, different applications are different processes.
But do you know that under some conditions Android may kill the process and restart its activities later? In this case your static variables will lose their values. (I think you already know that when you turn the screen (as well as in some other cases), the Activity is destroyed and re-created.)

Answer (score 0):

No, because every application runs in a completely separate process.